# Hw to do something if div DOES NOT have class-a or class-b or class-c?

Tags: jquery, html

For some reason this code is only catching the first div in the *if statement*. If I *remove* the *"!"* (is not) all of these are true. If I add the "!" only one of them is true.

I know I can use CSS and :not to display: none, but I need to remove these elements from the DOM.

Can you tell me what I'm missing here?

```js
$(".filtr-item").each(function() {
    // If this does not have class item-1 or item-1 or item-1 or item-1
    if (! $( this ).hasClass( "item-1" ) || $(this).hasClass( "item-2" ) || $(this).hasClass( "item-3" ) || $(this).hasClass( "item-4" ) ) {
   
       // Add class red
        $(this).remove();
    } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filtr-item item-1">Red</div>
<div class="filtr-item item-2">Red</div>
<div class="filtr-item item-3">Red</div>
<div class="filtr-item">Black</div>
<div class="filtr-item">Black</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `not()` to filter out the items.

```js
$(".filtr-item")
  .not(".item-1,.item-2,.item-3,.item-4")
    .remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filtr-item item-1">Red</div>
<div class="filtr-item item-2">Red</div>
<div class="filtr-item item-3">Red</div>
<div class="filtr-item">Black</div>
<div class="filtr-item">Black</div>
```

Problem with your code is the logic is wrong. It says if it is not item-1 or it is item-2 or it is item-2 or is item-4.

it needs to be wrapped

```
var elem = $(this);
if (! (elem.hasClass("item-1") || elem.hasClass("item-2") || elem.hasClass("item-3") || elem.hasClass("item-4") )) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with the logic in the `if` statement. You can fix this by adding `!` to every condition, and using `&&`, not `||`:

```js
$(".filtr-item").each(function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass("item-1") && !$(this).hasClass("item-2") && !$(this).hasClass("item-3") && !$(this).hasClass("item-4")) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filtr-item item-1">Red</div>
<div class="filtr-item item-2">Red</div>
<div class="filtr-item item-3">Red</div>
<div class="filtr-item">Black</div>
<div class="filtr-item">Black</div>
```

Comment: Interesting. Totally my mistake, I thought "&&" meant "and" vs "or" and would require each div to have all classes. Learning something new every day! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a `!` in an OR series of questions will work. So whatever classes you have, just list them and add `!`.

```js
$(".filtr-item").each(function() {
  // If this does not have class item-1 or item-1 or item-1 or item-1
  if (!($(this).hasClass("item-1") || $(this).hasClass("item-2") || $(this).hasClass("item-3") || $(this).hasClass("item-4"))) {

    // Add class red
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filtr-item item-1">Red</div>
<div class="filtr-item item-2">Red</div>
<div class="filtr-item item-3">Red</div>
<div class="filtr-item">Black</div>
<div class="filtr-item">Black</div>
```

But don't forget to wrap the whole condition inside like this:

```
if (!(hasClass || hasClass || hasClass))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either add the `!` to each condition or wrap them in parenthesis to check them all at once, but you can write it more concise with `.is()` like this:

```js
$(".filtr-item").each(function() {
    // If this does not have class item-1 or item-1 or item-1 or item-1
    if ( !$(this).is('.item-1, .item-2, .item-3, .item-4') ) {
        // Remove item
        $(this).remove();
    } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filtr-item item-1">Red</div>
<div class="filtr-item item-2">Red</div>
<div class="filtr-item item-3">Red</div>
<div class="filtr-item">Black</div>
<div class="filtr-item">Black</div>
```